If statement django template correct construction
Could someone help me to find the correct way to construct the template in django.
If the view object is edited by moderator (user is not owner) I put into context an object that has permissions as attributes. For example, object.permission_profile is boolean field that allows to edit user-owner profile.
So, in template I suggest I need to use if-statement to put necessary url, one url - when both object exists and permission is True, and another url - if object is not in context.
I put into template if-statement such way
{% if object %} {% if object.permission %} url-1 {% endif %} {% else %} url-2 {% endif %}

Is this correct way?
Or is there another right or faster rule to use it?
Thank you!

typically you can make a property in the object class that, depending on the .permission, returns one of the two urls, simplifying the template, and moving business logic to the model.

Thanks, its a good idea in general, but in my case it is particularly complicated, as I use different pairs of url-1 and url-2 in various places of template. For instance, one pair to create, another one to edit, and another one to delete some of object properties or related objects. I will also consider to move the logic to template filter

if object is unnecessary.
because if object is none, object.permission return none in template.
{% if object.permission %}
url-1
{% else %}
url-2
{% endif %}


An object contains different permissions. There is a case when an object exists but has no certain permission. In this case template does not show any urls

if not have permission or not have object, template use else option.
